# Converting to an immutable gpio chip

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gpio

I have spent the last 10 hours trying to boot asahi linux on my M1 Mac, and now I can finally run the boot command. However, when I run it, there is an error message that says `[0.202844] gpio gpiochip0: (macsmc-pmu-gpio): not an immutable chip, please consider fixing it!`
I haven't found any resources on how a user can fix this online. Please help.